# Piping between exceptions

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I was writing code in eclipse when a compile error suggested I add exceptions.  I clicked on the add exception to existing catch statement and it created a catch block that looked like this:

```
try{

}catch(SQLException | InvalidKeyException | BadPaddingException
            | IllegalBlockSizeException | NoSuchAlgorithmException
            | NoSuchPaddingException e){

        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have never seen that syntax before but it ran fine through eclipse.  When I ran it through my AIX server I got these errors:

```
forecast_transmission_v2.java:813: <identifier> expected
            }catch(SQLException | InvalidKeyException
                               ^
forecast_transmission_v2.java:813: '{' expected
            }catch(SQLException | InvalidKeyException
                                 ^
forecast_transmission_v2.java:814: illegal start of expression
                            | BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException
                            ^
forecast_transmission_v2.java:814: ';' expected
                            | BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException
                                                 ^
forecast_transmission_v2.java:815: not a statement
                            | NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e){
                                                       ^
forecast_transmission_v2.java:815: ';' expected
                            | NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e){
                                                                               ^
forecast_transmission_v2.java:815: not a statement
                            | NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e){
                                                                                ^
forecast_transmission_v2.java:815: ';' expected
                            | NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e){
```

I am assuming that this syntax is something new to Java7 and that is why this is happening.  Can anyone verify this or is there another reason for this error?

Comment: You have a problem on lines 813 - 815, as it says in the errors. Could you post those lines?

Comment: your AIX server is *not* running Java version 7 or higher!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is indeed a [Java 7 feature](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java7exceptions-486908.html).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this syntax is new to Java 7. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html